# CoreMIDI memory leaks?

Tags: coremidi

I'm put together a CoreMIDI iOS app where I'm testing MIDINetSessionBrowser and MIDINetworkSession. I've been looking at this for a while now, and it appears that CoreMIDI has memory leaks.

Also, I just tried Pete Goodliffe's CoreMIDI objective-c demo and it also generates memory leaks when I run through profiler!

Thus, I think the chances that I'm missing something are smaller :)

Has anyone else profiled CoreMIDI and found the same?
Note: I'm using latest XCode and latest iOS and profiling by running on iPod touch 4 device.

Answer (score 0):

I've some memory leaks due to CoreMIDI too.
It appears that the same issue still remains on iOS 5.0. 
By the way, I'm not using PGMidi classes, but only the CoreMIDI API.